# ExpandableListView Change layout of first child

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to load two different layouts into my expandable list *child*. I keep getting a null pointer, which to me sounds like my `!=0` is not actually working the way I intended. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
   boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    Log.e("COMMENTS", "Ok so the POSITION: " + childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(childPosition==0){
            //first view
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_create_comment, null);
        }else {
            //second view
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_expandable_list_child, null);
        }
    }
    if(childPosition!=0){
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments_expandable_list_child_text_view);
        ImageView delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments_expandable_list_child_delete);
        //throwing a null pointer exception at the delete.setonclick 
        //I'm guessing it's still using the first view here somehow?
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<String> child = comments_feed_collection.get(group_list.get(groupPosition));
                child.remove(childPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        item.setText(laptop);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Exact print out:

```
04-22 10:27:58.762  21013-21013/com.myapp E/COMMENTS﹕ Ok so the POSITION: 0
04-22 10:27:58.772  21013-21013/com.myapp I/Editor﹕ setup window support handles
04-22 10:27:58.772  21013-21013/com.myapp E/COMMENTS﹕ Ok so the POSITION: 1
04-22 10:27:58.772  21013-21013/com.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4183fda0)
04-22 10:27:58.792  21013-21013/com.myapp E/oh nooo﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at comments.CommentsExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(CommentsExpandableListAdapter.java:58)
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` you say? Tell us the problematic line you should.

Comment: right where my comment is, the delete.setOnClick line.

Comment: set ImageView as clickable : delete.setClickable(true);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem lies here:

```
 if (convertView == null) {
        if(childPosition==0){
            //first view
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_create_comment, null);
        }else {
            //second view
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_expandable_list_child, null);
        }
 }
```

`convertView` is null `getChildTypeCount` times. If you didn't override this method, `convertView` will be inflated just once. Most probably for your `childPosition==0` case. You can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildTypeCount()) the documentation

Comment: So i should @override   public View getChildView?

Comment: getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType for the children

Comment: I'm sorry, where are these methods exactly?

Comment: Yes that's your problem. `convertView` is sometimes not null but yet is not a the type your would expect for the current position. Use `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` to get around this ;)

Comment: In your case it is getChildType and getChildTypeCount. [Here:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildTypeCount()) the documeation

Comment: Yes I see, thanks. Please add that to the answer for future readers :)